# Display Tooltip only when text overflows - Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to have a Tooltip that is activated only if the text inside the Grid "overflows".

In my example, the Tooltip should show only the "very long title". https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-hamilton-9q6q6

I tried using useRef with little success since the width I am comparing have the same dimension https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-beaver-296w4 <--Code below

```
export default function App() {
  const titles = [
    "Short title",
    "Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery looooooooooooooog tiiiiiiiiiitle"
  ];

  const [isOverflowed, setIsOverflow] = useState(false);

  const textElementRef = useRef();
  const containerElementRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOverflow(
      textElementRef.current.scrollWidth >
        containerElementRef.current.clientWidth
    );
    console.log("A", textElementRef.current.scrollWidth); // Same dimension as one line below
    console.log("B", containerElementRef.current.clientWidth); // Same dimension as one line above
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {titles.map((title) => (
        <Grid item xs={6} ref={containerElementRef}>
          <Tooltip title={title} disableHoverListener={isOverflowed}>
            <OutlinedInput
              value={title}
              fullWidth
              disabled
              ref={textElementRef}
            />
          </Tooltip>
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```